# How can I remove all characters after the first instance of a tab?

Tags: java, inputstream, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter, inputstreamreader

I have a large text file, around 200,000 lines of word translations. I want to keep the translated text, which appears after the tab.

```
abaxial van  osovine
abbacy  opatstvo
abbaino     kora
abbatial    opatski
abbe    opat
abbé    opat
abbé    sveæenik
hematological parameters    hematološki pokazatelji
```

How can I get strip all characters before the first instance of a tab?

Comment: `text.split("\\s{2}\\s*")`

Comment: Just tested, and only removes strings before two spaces, but not for 1, 3, 4, etc...

Comment: For some reason ``String content = line.substring(line.lastIndexOf("\t") + 1);`` worked for me.

Comment: @MartinErlic That's weird, because `\t` is **not a space**. Perhaps your question should be: "How do I remove all text before the first **tab** character?". Or last, as your code snippet does it.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't realize that. They all seem to be tabs, but some are of different sizes.

Comment: @MartinErlic Then perhaps you should figure out what the data is, before you try to manipulate it. Use a good text editor that will show you spaces and tabs, e.g. [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/).

Comment: Confused!!! Question title *"remove all characters **after** a tab"*. Question text: *"strip all characters **before** two spaces"*. Is it tab or 2 spaces? Is it text before or after that needs to be eliminated?

Comment: If the question isn't about spaces, then please edit the text of the question to reflect that.

Comment: We've had better questions on this site, to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex to match everything before the translation:

```
 .+? {2,}
```

Try this regex online: https://regex101.com/r/P0TY1k/1

Use this regex to call `replaceAll` on your string.

```
yourString.replaceAll(".+? {2,}", "");
```

EDIT: If the delimiter is not 2 spaces but a tab, you can try this regex instead:

```
.+?(?: {2,}|\t)
```

Comment: Sorry, good answer, but question was wrong, and the "2 spaces" was actually a tab character. See [comment to question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47860805/remove-all-characters-after-the-first-instance-of-a-character-that-follows-more#comment82686635_47860805).

Comment: Question says *"first instance of ..."*, so shouldn't the regex begin with `.+?`? With a [greedy quantifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#greedy) like `.+`, it will replace all up to *last* instance, not first. A [reluctant quantifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#reluc) like `.+?` will stop at first instance.

Comment: @Andreas I see that the original/translation pairs are all in separate lines, so that wouldn't make a difference would it? Edited anyway.

Answer (score 0):

So you could use regex to do the string manipulated pretty efficently.

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

```
/**
 * Splits the line related to translation into 2 groups by splitting it on
 * two spaces " " and storing the splits into two named groups (key,
 * value)&lt;/br&gt;
 * Group1 (key) is the text before the two spaces.&lt;/br&gt;
 * Group2 (value) is the text after the two spaces.&lt;/br&gt;
 */
private static final Pattern TRANSLATION_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("<key>.*)\\s\\s+(<value>.*)");

public static String grabTextAfterTwoSpaces(String input) {
    Matcher matcher = TRANSLATION_PATTERN.matcher(input);

    /*
     * You have to call .matches() for the regex to actually be applied.
     */
    if (!matcher.matches()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Provided input:[%s] did not contain two spaces", input));
    }

    return matcher.group("value");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(grabTextAfterTwoSpaces("abaxial van  osovine"));
    System.out.println(grabTextAfterTwoSpaces("abbacy  opatstvo"));
    System.out.println(grabTextAfterTwoSpaces("abbaino     kora"));
    System.out.println(grabTextAfterTwoSpaces("abbatial    opatski"));
    System.out.println(grabTextAfterTwoSpaces("abbe    opat"));
    System.out.println(grabTextAfterTwoSpaces("abbé    opat"));
    System.out.println(grabTextAfterTwoSpaces("abbé    sveæenik"));
    System.out.println(grabTextAfterTwoSpaces("abbacy  opatstvo"));

    System.out.println(grabTextAfterTwoSpaces("hematological parameters    hematološki pokazatelji"));
}
```

}

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVTNbtNAEL7nKQZLSE4ojuAG/UE5VKgSLVWTC2orNLY3ziabXWt37CSgPAwXJJ6j4rnC2F43QbRIkK4trb0z88038409xRJfmlzoaTp7s9l05Dw3lmDKx1FBUkVWZGIZnSMlE2EPH7NfIpGw@rDTyYtYyQQShc7BOUoNXzsd4NXv9eodejDMlSQHNBGgpBZghUISKZABsqgdv0mjQWo@eA2ZNUXuIF6Bq@JI6gwkgdEtHC0MmzARDgK@UKfgyNjKr0rhmmw1WuWqcc65PGo4E6uDFqhEVYjuUT@2J@3R@8rtVe3WBdlwJrEkiMXYWNG83@eP/ox9DWED@1s0jrldfwvu13tuZcmd4XK4IwmMpUYFvtcwuhpcDD8MRmcfLz5fDkaj06sLOG6tUWLmuVQiDMJ3R0z@JOp1b24c3y/4oGZUHQXdw0YdL5tPNKS6e5nFeMR0BxXb0cIMa56ht0qdF9RlecEvPyQw9/vxQxQjbw2bcJ@@GZD7R27eJ1PABEtRDUWCSoEPdGEXuPN17@rZqxwwoYJ9VqwKYM56izTaAevfP8sxhM88gy3gbhHVook1C9BiAWdKiQzVwGbFXGg6XSYir2bT9yBiJowSBpfWlDLlsaqrenv93N1CKlPQhiAxmqrvYKt0cOCbx@W3OdfbRlhBBevb0qwnNQxqzQIfsX5ItdJwxjmn8uyubwFt5narG64ciXlkCop4tjQpHT4icoAxLiWPW4kawDiuT3P6Hcb/hBVjsmKYHMlRafbBkdrUYTNjcR8cqooDz2km94ASLcweGHc/ngzEleLuu9By9qRq/Q/QRPAMG2UyyV8w5Gj5z8seroJpbT@/zSTkZoZf@Eenplsd1p31ZvML)

So if you use "value" for the group you'll get everything after the 2+ spaces.

> osovine
>
> opatstvo
>
> kora
>
> opatski
>
> opat
>
> opat
>
> sveæenik
>
> opatstvo
>
> hematološki pokazatelji

Comment: Sorry, good answer, but question was wrong, and the "2 spaces" was actually a tab character. See [comment to question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47860805/remove-all-characters-after-the-first-instance-of-a-character-that-follows-more#comment82686635_47860805).